# XGBoostError: need to call fit or load_model beforehand - Train a model with dask GridSearchCV and XGBoost

Tags: python

I'm trying to train a model using Dask and XGBoost, but my code fails when it tries to fit the model:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
from dask_ml.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
data = dd.read_csv('data.csv', storage_options={'anon': True})
X = data.drop('A', axis=1)
y = data['A']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2, shuffle=True)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
params = {
    'max_depth':[1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    'n_estimators':np.arange(50, 500, 50),
    'max_features':['sqrt', 'log2', None]
}

search = GridSearchCV(model, params)
result = search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (result.best_score_, result.best_params_))
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, what line gives the error?

Comment: 'search.fit(X_train, y_train)' gives me the XGBoostError: need to call fit or load_model beforehand error